# How do I write this Django query in regular SQL?

Tags: python, sql, mysql, database, django

```
results = Content.objects.filter(next_decay_at__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that did the ORM of Django is equivalent (Django got the datetime directly from Python) to:

```
SELECT field1, field2, fieldn FROM app_content WHERE next_decay_at <= NOW()
```

NOW() is a SQL function that provide the actual datetime.
You can get more info at:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_now.asp

Comment: With the caveat that if the `Content.objects` Manager modifies the queryset there may be other clauses in `WHERE`.  For example, a blog `Post` model where `Post.objects` is set to a manager that filters out posts in the future.

Comment: Yes, you're right. My answer is valid only if no one has altered the Manager by adding more conditions to the where clause.

Comment: If I want to use datetime.datetime.now() instead of NOW(), how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out exactly what Django sends with `results._as_sql()`.  In your particular case it's going to write a query with the specific date you passed in.  If you were really writing the query directly in SQL you'd probably want to use a symbolic `NOW()` instead.

Comment: note that in 1.2.3 `results._as_sql()` requires an argument (connection). It looks like it was for internal use for the `__in` lookups and doesn't actually return the full SQL generated. Use `print results.query` or `results.query.__str__()` for the actual query sent to db. PS: Portland rocks!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider leveraging https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar and check out the SQL tab. You'll get a chance to see all queries ran within your app.